# Android Studio : Cannot use class from src in Unit tests

Tags: android-studio, unit-testing, gradle, junit

since the last Update (of Android Studio ? or Gradle ?) I cannot import code from prod in my tests classes.

A few months ago, the tests were working without any problems.
I can launch the tests, using gradle in command line, or using AndroidStudio test runner. And it work nice : it passes when the code is ok, it fails when there is a bug.

But the auto-completion isn't working, the class, methods ... are red.
I cannot click on an object to navigate to the declaration ... and so on.

And the AndroidStudio automatic quickfix is : "add dependency on module xxx"
which add a line in the gradle file :
`implementation project(path: ':app')`

I have the same problem on several project, with gradle 6.1.1 or 7.2.1

AndroidStudio version is :
Chipmunk, 2021.2.1 patch 1
built on May 18 2022

the unit test, in app/src/test/java/com/apackage/ASimpleTest.kt

```
package com.apackage


import org.junit.Test
import kotlin.test.assertEquals

class ASimpleTest {

    @Test
    fun aTest(){

        val plop = AClass()
        assertEquals(1, plop.aMethod())
    }
}
```

the class in app/src/main/java/com/apackage/AClass.kt:

```
package com.apackage

class AClass {
    fun aMethod() = 1
}
```

I have no problem calling a method in the same folder as the tests.
The problem is test/main folder calling src/main

Comment: Facing the same problem with Android Studio Dolphin.

Comment: @GaspardP and James did you find any solution? I'm also facing similar problem in AS Dolphin

Comment: Facing the same issue with Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Patch 2  and Java 11.

Answer (score 2):

You got to add the `'src/test/java'` and `'src/main/java'` to the sourceSets in your app `build.gradle`

```
android {
    // Other configuration options...

    sourceSets {
        test {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java', 'src/main/java']
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add app module as a testImplementation dependency to app module build.gradle file like this. this will help you get rid of it.

```
dependencies {

    //blah blah blah

    //this is what you should add
    testImplementation project(path: ':app')
}
```